# Change the value for a Widget KeyValue Switch SetValue within Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons, google-apps-script-addon

I'm not understanding how to `setValue` for the switch. I want to be able to have an on/off using a users stored value.

Over at the [Google Scripts CardService Switch Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/switch) they have show this example:

```
var switchKeyValue = CardService.newKeyValue()
    .setTopLabel("Switch key value widget label")
    .setContent("This is a key value widget with a switch on the right")
    .setSwitch(CardService.newSwitch()
        .setFieldName("form_input_switch_key")
        .setValue("form_input_switch_value") // <-- note that part
        .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction()
            .setFunctionName("handleSwitchChange")));
```

When I try to `setValue` I never see the switch get toggled to an `on` state. I know that setValue needs to be a string, and I've tried the example above, and equally, I've tried:

```
const value = true;

...

  .setValue(value.toString())
...
```

I can say even without supplying a value, it's still false/off.

How do change the state of a switch widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [`Switch.setSelected(boolean)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/switch#setSelected(Boolean))

`setSelected` will set the initial state of the switch.

Comment: You are a hero! Thank you very much! So small question, if you happen to know, why is `setValue` there?

Comment: @KellyTheDev - `setFieldName` does not need to be unique.  If you have multiple switches with the same _name_, then you will get back an _array_ of values.  Therefore,  `setValue` lets you set different values for a bunch of switches that all have the same name.